# Is it possible to stream sdtout/stderr output from node-ssh exec()

Tags: node.js, ssh

Using [`node-ssh` JS library](https://github.com/steelbrain/node-ssh), one can execute remote commands. Is it possible to get streamed output from a long-running command, as it is generated? (Without waiting the command to end).

The example in the project page suggests you can only get stdout and stderr once the command is done:

```
ssh.execCommand('hh_client --json', { cwd:'/var/www'})
.then(function(result) {
    console.log('STDOUT: ' + result.stdout)
    console.log('STDERR: ' + result.stderr)
})
```

Comment: It does not appear so. You'd have to either find another library that does or use `ssh2` directly.

Comment: ok. That's my current approach, I have a working implementation already (alas, using both libraries and stopping one connection on node-ssh to create one on ssh2). I wanted to stick to `node-ssh` as I had started from there and I was liking the promises (plus await, async) flow! Thanks.

Comment: You might submit an issue and/or PR to the `node-ssh` project about adding such functionality then.